# How do I set axis label style in chaco?

Tags: python, syntax, plot, traits, chaco

I am trying to change the axis labels on my plots in Chaco. I have generated with some code similar to the following:

```
thisplot=Plot(alldata)
thisplot.plot("xdata","ydata",value_scale="log",index_scale="log")
```

I would like to use the `_nice_sci()` formatting for the labels from the `BasicFormatter` class as the range is quite large (on the loglog plot) but can't work out the syntax.

Does anyone have any tips for implementing this?